# Spring Boot Configuration -- keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Controller:

```
    package com.example.ex.controller;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public class KeycloakController {


        @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String adminPage() {
            return "redirect:admin.html";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/user", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String userPage() {
            return "redirect:user.html";
        }
    }
```

This is the application.properties file

```
keycloak.realm = finaltest
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.resource = ex
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.credentials.secret=2462fa5e-2f23-496f-a28f-b13ad7948999
keycloak.ssl-required = external
#keycloak.bearer-only=true
#keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
#keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.autodetect-bearer-only=true
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
keycloak.security-constraints[0].auth-roles[0]=slave
keycloak.security-constraints[0].auth-roles[1]=master
keycloak.security-constraints[0].security-collections[0].patterns[0]=/*
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].path=/admin
#keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
```

keycloak.json:

```
{
  "realm": "finaltest",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8180/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "ex",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "2462fa5e-2f23-496f-a28f-b13ad7948999"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

Error StackTrace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not obtain configuration from server [http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/finaltest/.well-known/uma-configuration].
            at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.<init>(AuthzClient.java:92) ~[keycloak-authz-client-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.create(AuthzClient.java:64) ~[keycloak-authz-client-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.authorization.PolicyEnforcer.<init>(PolicyEnforcer.java:61) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:143) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:169) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:37) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:88) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:107) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:79) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:177) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
        Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 404 / Not Found
            at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:95) ~[keycloak-authz-client-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$2.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:48) ~[keycloak-authz-client-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            at org.keycloak.authorization.client.AuthzClient.<init>(AuthzClient.java:90) ~[keycloak-authz-client-3.4.2.Final.jar:3.4.2.Final]
            ... 22 common frames omitted
```

So what should i do,to get rid of these errors?
I just have problems in integrating spring boot application with keycloak.

[Keycloak realm[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQsd6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQsd6.png)

Is it necessary to include keycloak.json file in the resources of the application?

Comment: Can you share more detail from the stack trace.

Comment: yes added more details

Comment: Does the realm finaltest exist in your local keycloak?

Comment: yes it does,do i have to configure something in keycloak

Comment: You just have to make sure the realm finaltest exists and the resource ex is configured in your KeyCloak. Try testing with this minimal configuration: keycloak.realm=finaltest
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.resource=ex
keycloak.credentials.secret=2462fa5e-2f23-496f-a28f-b13ad7948999
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.cors=true
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.ssl-required=external

Comment: ya thats working,but when i give keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
#keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].path=/admin,then its not working

Comment: Check your keycloak.json, is policy-enforcer enabled?

Comment: yes its enabled,i have added that file too.is it necessary to have keycloak.json file while we have configured in application.properties?

Comment: @sechanakira how to pass parameters from application.properties to keycloak for policy evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better you can use spring boot 2 adapter (version above 2.0.0) and use latest version of keycloak(4.5.0 or 4.6.0) , because it have backward compatibilty.